# removing links from posts in wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress, hyperlink, posts

I have few blogs for some clients. I need to remove links to one of my clients in all posts. Just to be clear i need to remove links and my keyword should stay like it is.
I found this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/automatically-remove-links-from-posts/installation/

But this one remove all links.

I need to remove all links just for one client, and links for other clients should stay unchanged.

Does anyone know about some good plugin for this solution?
Is there any way using SQL statements? I need solution to recognize link no meter what is keyword and to remove href text leaving keyword unchanged.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using regex .. Create a regex pattern and use in this plugin .This will search and replace them with `''`

This is the [**plugin**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/)

Try and let know